# How to create RequiredFieldValidator at the same time as textboxes that I generated in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In C# server side codes, I already successful created a textboxes based on user select how many they want to fill it out. Now I want to created a RequiredFieldValidators to validate these textboxes I generated to ensure that the users doesn't leave the textboxes blank. I don't know how that work but I am sure it need to put inside foreach loop to create validators at the same time as textboxes. Please help

C# codes,

```
 int num = 1;

        foreach(PSObject psObject in output)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            Label ipLabel = new Label();
            ipLabel.Text = psObject + "<br/>";
            TextBox t = new TextBox();
            t.ID = "textBoxName" + num.ToString();
            div.Controls.Add(ipLabel);
            div.Controls.Add(t);
            phDynamicTextBox.Controls.Add(div);
            tbids.Add(t.ID);
            num++;
        }

        Session["tbids"] = tbids;
```

HTML codes,

```
<div id="div1" runat="server">
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phDynamicTextBox" runat="server" />
        </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make RequiredFieldValidator in aspx.cs (code behind) asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18275125/make-requiredfieldvalidator-in-aspx-cs-code-behind-asp-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to create RequiredFieldValidator similar to Label and TextBox control.

Only difference is you need to assign TextBox's ID to ControlToValidate.

```
...
TextBox t = new TextBox();
t.ID = "textBoxName" + num.ToString();
div.Controls.Add(ipLabel);
div.Controls.Add(t);

var rfv = new RequiredFieldValidator();
rfv.ID = "RequiredFieldValidator" + num;
rfv.ControlToValidate = t.ID;
rfv.ErrorMessage = num + " is required.";
div.Controls.Add(rfv);

phDynamicTextBox.Controls.Add(div);
...
```

Comment: I got that worked, how do I add `<br />` to move validator underneath the textbox?

Comment: StudentIT : phDynamicTextBox.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));

Comment: @Bartdude, that doesn't work because the validator is still next to textbox.

Comment: Well it depends on where you did put this instruction... but better create another question, or search for similar answers on SO (there's a lot of it)

Comment: Nevermind, I got it worked, I was putting in wrong order. It was suppose to put `div.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));` above `div.Controls.Add(textValidate);`. Not after.

Answer (score 3):

@Win Answer is correct, here is a fancy way to do it:

```
var textBoxValidator = new RequiredFieldValidator
{
    ID = "textBoxValidator" + num,
    ControlToValidate = t.ID,
    Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic,
    ErrorMessage = String.Format("The TextBox field #{0} Cannot be blank", num),
    ForeColor = Color.Red
};


div.Controls.Add(textBoxValidator);
```